# Error of context consumer rendered with multiple children

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Getting error of:

> A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child
> that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that
> is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no
> trailing or leading whitespace around it.

At first it was working but then the error started showing up. This is a vite + tailwindcss + react APP. I got error of cannot render context directly, so I added the Consumer code. But then this new error came up.

This is the context I created:

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react'

// creating the food context
export const FoodContext = createContext()
export const FoodProvider = (props) => {

// state for the details
const [foods, setFoods] = useState([
{
            title: 'Dougnut',
            source: 'Delicious soft Dougnut',
            price: 500,
            imageUrl: "url('./images/pizza.jpg')",
            id: 1,
            buttonText: 'Order'
        },
        {
            title: 'Pasta',
            source:'Delicous pasta',
            price: 1500,
            imageUrl: '../images/banner.jpg',
            id: 6,
            buttonText: 'Order'
        }
    ]);

    return (
        <div>
            <FoodContext.Provider value={[foods, setFoods]}>
                {props.children}
            </FoodContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the main.js file where I wrapped all my contents with the context:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { FoodContext } from './components/context/FoodContext';

ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
      <FoodContext.Consumer>
          <App />
      </FoodContext.Consumer>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And this is my app.js file:

```
import {Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {FoodProvider} from "./components/context/FoodContext";
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import SingleFood from './components/SingleFood';

function App() {
  // const consumer = React.useContext(FoodProvider);
  return (
    <FoodProvider.Consumer>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
           <Route path='/menu' component={Menu } />
           <Route path='/food/:id' component={SingleFood } />
           <Route path='*' component={NotFound } />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </FoodProvider.Consumer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here there are different problems:

1. I think you are using the consumer before declaring the provider. A context consumer must be a child (not direct) of the provider. To understand how context should be managed I suggest you gaining some knowledge about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) first and then re-think your implementation.
2. You can pass your state to the provider without putting the elements in a list. Using: `<FoodContext.Provider value={{foods, setFoods}}>` allows you to better destructure your context in children components.
3. Your usage of the consumer doesn't also respect how you should use it. As you can see from the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) you should insert a single object based on the consumer value. So in your specific case, when you want to list your foods, you should have something like this:

```
 <FoodContext.Consumer>
  {
    ({ foods, setFoods }) => foods.map(food => (
      <div className="food-item">
        <h1>{food.title}</h1>
        {/*The remaining elements of your food component*/}
      </div>
    ))
  }
</FoodContext.Consumer>
```